# Why is “so that” improper in “I was tired so that I couldn't sleep”?

Tags: conjunctions

> d) I was so tired that I couldn't sleep
>
> **e) I was tired so that I couldn't sleep**
>
> Of these two examples d) is perfect and e) simply doesn't work.
>
> d) is the correct form of e) or an alternative would be I was too tired to sleep.

One of my friends has explained this to me. Nevertheless, I couldn't get ***why*** *E* is incorrect.

there -- at the link-- has been written tow kinds of "so that", hasn't been written? if so, we could use them interchageably by the meaning both result and purpose.

I have ***underlined*** what I mean:

[enter link description here](https://www.mediafire.com/?4x434awm6hdmd5q)

Comment: Try walking us through why you think it is proper.  What's the intent of the sentence?  How does the sentence convey that intent?

Comment: Considering the link provided, I am looking forward for another answer

Comment: the link says that so that could mean both result and purpose. So, now is E correct?

Comment: there has been written tow kinds of "so that", hasn't been written? if so, we could use them interchageably by the meaning both result and purpose.

Comment: why?what?I cannot get it

Answer (score 25):

The phrase "***so that***" means "*for the purpose of*". It shows *intent* or *purpose*.

> **Correct:** I went to the market *so that* I could buy food.
>
> - (I went to the market *for the purpose of* buying food.)
>
> **Correct:** She put on a coat *so that* she would not be cold.
>
> - (She put on a coat *for the purpose of* not being cold.)

The sentence "I was tired so that I couldn't sleep" doesn't make sense.

> **Incorrect:** I was tired so that I couldn't sleep.
>
> - (I was tired *for the purpose of* not being able to sleep.)

This is difficult to read sensibly. It might mean that you made yourself tired with the intention of not being able to sleep.

On the other hand, ***so... that...*** is different from ***so that***. It indicates that an *extreme condition* causes *some consequence*:

> The desert was *so* hot *that* many of the soldiers passed out.
>
> - (The desert was very hot, and the heat caused many soldiers to pass out.)
>
> The rock was *so* big that we needed 10 people to move it.
>
> I was *so* tired *that* I couldn't sleep.

Comment: As I read it, the phrase in question uses it in the spirit of "Why are you frightened so?", as in "I was tired (in such a way) that I couldn't sleep.".

Comment: "This is difficult to read sensibly. It might mean that you made yourself tired with the intention of not being able to sleep."  It's easier (but not particularly likely to be found in the wild) if someone else did the tiring. E.g., you might tire (out) a child or pet so that it will sleep.  "When I was young, my parents would take me to the park.  I was tired [by them] so that I could sleep."  Of course, this gets much more difficult in when OP is so tired that OP *couldn't* sleep.

Answer (score 4):

In d) *so* is modifying tired (how tired you are). This is an adverb usage, sense 2 in the definition linked below. This usage is correct.

In e) *so* precedes a phrase explaining the result of being tired (I couldn't sleep). But *that* is out of place. Check the example in Collins [so](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/so) sense 8. Here it is a conjunction.

I would write sentence e) this way:

> e) I was tired **so** I couldn't sleep.

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences work fine, but they have different meanings.
d means I was really tired resulting in not able to sleep.
e means I was a bit tired resulting in not able to sleep.

Comment: is this answer correct?

Comment: @nima_persian - ***"is this answer correct?"*** - No.